# Issues uploading VHD in Azure Powershell with Add-AzureVHD commandlet

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-storage

I'm attempting what should be a pretty basic task.  I've created a local VHD of a workstation template that I want to upload for use in my Azure environment.  I'm working from Azure Powershell.

I've uploaded my .cer file to create a management certificate.  I've imported the .publishsettings file and I'm able to use Set-AzureSubscription and Select-AzureSubscription with no apparent issues:

```
Set-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName "Windows Azure Enterprise" -CurrentStorageAccount ATOQA

Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName "Windows Azure Enterprise"
```

The problem I run into is this when I attempt to use Add-AzureVHD:

```
PS C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\.NET SDK\2012-10\bin> add-azurevhd -destination "https://ATOQA.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/ztemplate-W7.vhd" -localfilepath "C:\VM\W7_Template\ztemplate-w7.vhd"
add-azurevhd : "An exception occurred when calling the ServiceManagement API. HTTP Status Code: 404. Service Management Error Code: ResourceNotFound. Message: The requested storage account 
'atoqa' was not found.. Operation Tracking ID: df91c24901254047b39a7a7d5b037ea0."
At line:1 char:1
+ add-azurevhd -destination "https://ATOQA.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/ztemplate-W7 ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Add-AzureVhd], ServiceManagementClientException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.ServiceManagement.StorageServices.AddAzureVhdCommand
```

I'm fairly certain that the information I'm using to specify the -destination is correct, since I've copied it directly from the container URL field on the Azure site.

Where am I going wrong?  I've been using a few websites as guides to give you an idea of what I've been working from:

http://www.cloudtec.ch/blog/tech/upload-vhd-to-azure.html

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn205185.aspx

I've also attempted to use CSUPLOAD with the same basic steps and get a message that states "storage account was not found", leading me to believe i'm populating a parameter with the wrong information, but I'm really confused on what my mistake is exactly.

Many, many thanks in advance!

Comment: Just a guess but can you try by specifying the storage account name in lowercase?

Comment: I did try that as well, thinking that it was choking on the caps entry but it didn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Short Answer:**

Please ensure that your storage account is in the same subscription as specified in `Set-AzureSubscription`.

**Long Answer:**

What's happening (I think) is that when you call `Set-Subscription`, the cmdlet doesn't check if the storage account is in the same subscription. Now when you call, `Add-AzureVhd` and specify the destination URL, the cmdlet need to find the storage account key and makes use of [`Get Storage Account Keys`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460785.aspx) operation for that making use of subscription id and management certificate. Because this storage account does not exist in the specified subscription, you get Resource Not Found error.

Comment: That was exactly the problem.  As soon as I included the -SubscriptionId parameter it kicked off like a champ.  Many thanks!

Comment: when I ran Get-AzureSubscription it listed two subscriptions, and the one with my storage container was neither default or current. I ran the Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName <name> -Current cmdlet to make the correct subscription current, and then the Add-AzureVhd cmdlet worked.

Answer (score 4):

I was having problems with `Set-AzureSubscription`

`Select-AzureSubscription` did the trick.